# mysql query help

Tags: mysql

My query is:

```
SELECT business.name, AVG(rating.value) as total  
FROM business   
INNER JOIN rating   
   ON business.id = rating.business_id   
INNER JOIN directory   
   ON business.id = directory.item_id  
WHERE directory.directory_id = 13    
   AND directory.type = 'business'   
   AND rating.rating_id = '1'   
GROUP BY business.id   
ORDER BY total DESC
```

My problem is that I want to include any businesses even if they do not have any ratings associated with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT business.name, AVG(rating.value) as total  
FROM business   
INNER JOIN directory   
   ON business.id = directory.item_id  
LEFT JOIN rating   
   ON business.id = rating.business_id AND rating.rating_id = '1'
WHERE directory.directory_id = 13    
   AND directory.type = 'business'   
GROUP BY business.id   
ORDER BY total DESC
```

If there are no ratings, total will be NULL.
You can deal with this in MySQL (if you want) like this:

```
IFNULL(AVG(rating.value), 'No ratings') as total
```

Also note you need to move the `rating.rating_id = '1'` to the JOIN conditions.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had no idea you could add a "AND" directly to a join. Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` instead of your `INNER JOIN` when joining the `rating`-table.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change...

```
INNER JOIN rating
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN rating
```

An INNER JOIN returns a row where there is a match in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` when joining businesses and ratings

Answer (score -1):

You want to do a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).

```
SELECT business.name, AVG(rating.value) as total  
FROM business   
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating   
   ON business.id = rating.business_id   
INNER JOIN directory   
   ON business.id = directory.item_id  
WHERE directory.directory_id = 13    
   AND directory.type = 'business'   
   AND rating.rating_id = '1'   
GROUP BY business.id   
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: I read his question the wrong way. Strange how you could comment on my old answer even after I corrected it.